# Count in Dynamic Date Range

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table that has the fields: `customer_id`, `start_trial_date`, `end_trial_date`.  I am trying to write a query that I can use to count `customer_id`s on a given date.

```
|+-------------+------------+------------+
| customer_id | start_date |  end_date  |
+-------------+------------+------------+
|           1 | 2017-02-03 | 2017-05-01 |
|           2 | 2017-04-07 | 2017-09-01 |
|           3 | 2017-03-02 | 2018-03-04 |
|           4 | 2013-02-25 | 2015-01-22 |
|           5 | 2015-11-10 | 2016-03-25 |
|     ....    |     ....   |     ....   |
+-------------+------------+------------+
```

How would I write a query to produce a result set that has all dates in a range with a count of `customer_id`s whose eligible period includes that date?

Expected output:

```
+------------+-----------+
|    date    | customers |
+------------+-----------+
| 2013-01-01 | 0         |
| ….         | ….        |
| 2017-04-20 | 3         |
| …..        | ….        |
| 2018-12-31 | ….        |
+------------+-----------+
```

I'm using BigQuery if that matters.  I've considered creating a helper table that lists all dates for a range and then trying to join that to my table and counting, but I don't have a good join key in that approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a calendar table is a good starting point. Once you have that table in place (say table `calendar` with column `calendar_date`), then you can use `LEFT JOIN` and aggregation :

```
SELECT c.calendar_date, COUNT(t.customer_id) customers
FROM calendar c
LEFT JOIN mytable t 
    ON c.calendar_date >= t.start_date AND c.calendar_date <= t.end_date
GROUP BY c.calendar_date
```

NB : you may want to adapt the inequality conditions (`>=` or `>`, `<=` or `<`) according to your exact requirements.

Comment: Nice, thanks!  For future searchers, BigQuery didn't like this with the error, "LEFT OUTER JOIN cannot be used without a condition that is an equality of fields from both sides of the join".  The remedy is to use a Cross Join.

Answer (score 1):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
WITH calendar AS (
  SELECT day
  FROM (
    SELECT MIN(start_date) min_date, MAX(end_date) max_date
    FROM `project.dataset.table`
  ), UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY(min_date, max_date)) day
)
SELECT day, COUNTIF(day BETWEEN start_date AND end_date) customers
FROM calendar, `project.dataset.table`
GROUP BY day
```

You can test, play with above using dummy data as in below example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 1 customer_id, DATE '2017-01-01' start_date, DATE '2017-01-05' end_date UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, '2017-01-03', '2017-01-04' UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, '2017-01-04', '2017-01-06' UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, '2017-01-10', '2017-01-12' UNION ALL
  SELECT 5, '2017-01-12', '2017-01-13' 
), calendar AS (
  SELECT day
  FROM (
    SELECT MIN(start_date) min_date, MAX(end_date) max_date
    FROM `project.dataset.table`
  ), UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY(min_date, max_date)) day
)
SELECT day, COUNTIF(day BETWEEN start_date AND end_date) customers
FROM calendar, `project.dataset.table`
GROUP BY day
-- ORDER BY day
```

with result

```
Row day         customers    
1   2017-01-01  1    
2   2017-01-02  1    
3   2017-01-03  2    
4   2017-01-04  3    
5   2017-01-05  2    
6   2017-01-06  1    
7   2017-01-07  0    
8   2017-01-08  0    
9   2017-01-09  0    
10  2017-01-10  1    
11  2017-01-11  1    
12  2017-01-12  2    
13  2017-01-13  1
```

Comment: Very elegant and +1 for the BigQuery-specific solution.